# How to define "initial value" for a calculation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and an initial value `a(0)=0` for the following equation:

```
for k=1:n
    delta=a(k)-a(k-1);
end
```

I cant define `a(0)=0`. Any ideas how to calc `delta=a1-a0` ?

Comment: If you are really interested in this specific calculation, it may be good to know that an elegant solution would be: `diff(0:7)`

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB indexing starts at 1 and not 0. so what you did will work if you simply do this:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

for k=2:n 
  delta(k-1)=a(k)-a(k-1); 
end
```

or if you dont want to change the vector :

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

for k=1:n 
  if k>1
  delta(k-1)=a(k)-a(k-1);
  else 
  delta(1)=a(k);
end
```

or better yet, without the `if`

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
delta(1)=a(1);
for k=2:n 
  delta(k-1)=a(k)-a(k-1);    
end
```

Comment: is there a way not to put the zero in the vector a?

Comment: @jdoubleu In fact the zero is inside the vector in this answer. It is not possible to have a zero indexed vector (which you seemed to hope for).

Comment: @jdoubleu you could put an `if` that checks if k is larger than 0, and if not it will use the 0 value, I edited the answer to do that.

Comment: yep thanks! I think im gonna stick to your first option with the zero in the vector. I'll creat it like this:`a=[333,312,4214,414124,53534,342134];
L=length(a);
A=zeros(L,1);
for k=1:L
    A(k+1)=a(k);
end`

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to accomplish this. The simplist IMO is to use an if statement to check if k==1, then the inital condition applies:

```
delta = 0
for k = 1:n
    if k == 1
        delta=a(k)-0;
    else
        delta=a(k)-a(k-1);
    end
end
```

Comment: I've been thinking about this but the problem is that the calculation is not done yet. So I would have two huge calculations, one for k==1 and one for k>1